# Como trabalhar em equipe com Git num arquivo que é modificado em cada branch?

Tags: git

Estou trabalhando numa equipe de programadores que não tem muita famialiaridade com Git. A dúvida é:

Possuímos um arquivo X vital para o funcionamento do projeto. O problema é que em cada branch precisamos modificá-lo. Qual seria a solução ideal para não causar nenhum tipo de conflito?

Comment: ## Esses links podem te ajudar! - [Git // Dicionário do Programador](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=za5KWZ5pRag) - [Como trabalhar em equipe usando github e gitbash](https://medium.com/reprogramabr/como-trabalhar-em-equipe-usando-github-e-gitbash-cde37cab6526)

Comment: primeiro é interessante conhecer as ferramentas de manipulação de branchs. Saiba que conflitos são a coisa mais comum do mundo, o Git vai tentar lidar com eles sozinho, mas muitas vezes não será possível, principalmente se for um projeto grande, exigindo uma interferência direta do usuário

Answer (score 1):

Depende do tipo de arquivo. Arquivos binários não são favoráveis a serem usados com controle de verão dessa forma. Arquivos em texto são mais fáceis de fazer merge.

Agora, a questão do conflito em si é inevitável. O git, como qualquer outra ferramenta de VCS, vai apenas ajudar vocês a gerenciar os conflitos, mas evitá-los é impossível, cono você pode perceber na sua própria pergunta. O problema real é mais de comunicação entre os componentes do projeto.

O melhor nesse casos é estabelecer um protocolo de uso do arquivo. Algo como um email ou um canal de comunicação por chat da equipe, de forma que seja fácil saber quem está de posse naquele momento, por exemplo.